# Getting Error Feedback in Android

Tags: android

I'm writing a fairly simple app which, upon a fatal error, displays a dialog box apologising to the user.  This dialog has a button which gives the user the opportunity to let me know that the app has failed and why.

It seems a little overkill to create an email for this task - especially an email from the user themselves.  Is there a nice, simple way to send some feedback to me? This won't be an FC situation so Froyo's new feedback mechanism won't come into play.  Anyway - I'd like to get these reports from pre-Froyo users as well.

Comment: although it's not the exact same question there's some useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502435/how-can-you-debug-on-a-phone-you-dont-own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a while, I was using this:
http://talkingandroid.com/2009/11/04/droiddrop-remote-logging-for-android/

It uses a "drop" at http://drop.io to send any info you want. It's not perfect, but it did the job reasonably well until my drop got too large.

If this is something that's rather rare, it should be fine. My app was sending too many of them for exceptions that didn't matter all that much, and my user base grew more rapidly than I expected. Now I can't view my drop. Their system seems to have some scaling issues.

Once I revamp my error reporting to only send useful info, I'll probably give it another try.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks.  This looks like it might well do the trick.  I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using ACRA for error/crash reporting, I would recommend it, very easy to port and use.
ACRA -> http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Error reports are inserted into Google docs excel file, which makes is very easy to manage and track.

Answer (score 1):

You could display a webpage with a form that would send some data to your website, or use a script to upload a file to a server, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There's a startup called Crittercism (http:/www.crittercism.com) that does crash reporting collection with a nice web portal that organizes it all with a stacktrace.